# netbeans loading svn error :

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

Netbeans SVN loading Error:

Setting up SVN for NetBeans already took me lots of time, finally I got it 
the error
you need to get a newer Subversion client, or to downgrade this working copy. See http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change

We strongly recommend to either install a newer Subversion client or downgrade your working copy. Any local changes might corrupt your working copy and some file operations as copying, renaming and deleting will not work correctly.

Comment: **Solution** :
Creating a new workspace for Netbeans Project Will helps to avoid this error

Comment: Please post your solution as an *answer* and **accept** it, so other's can see this question as solved.